# How to set roles and users with correct permissions on Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My current database `uat` has as owner `postgres`. But now I would like to set roles and users with the correct permissions. Something simple like:

**roles**: `dba`, `developer`, `application`

**users**: `dba1`, `dev1`, `dev2`, `app1`

Where `dba` can do anything on the database for administration purposes; `developer` can makes `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT`, usual developer operations; `app1` the same operations as the `developer` role, for now.

How can I make this correctly ? And who should be the owner of my `production` table in this new setup ?

**UPDATE:**

```
------------------------
-- INITIAL SETUP
------------------------

-- create uat database
create database uat;

-- dba role
create role dba with superuser createdb createrole nologin replication bypassrls;

-- dev role
create role dev with nosuperuser nocreatedb nocreaterole nologin noreplication nobypassrls;

-- app role
create role app with nosuperuser nocreatedb nocreaterole nologin noreplication nobypassrls;

-- alter postgres password
alter role postgres encrypted password '';

-- create users

create user dev1 login inherit encrypted password '' in role dev;
create user dev2 login inherit encrypted password '' in role dev;
create user dev3 login inherit encrypted password '' in role dev;
create user dev4 login inherit encrypted password '' in role dev;

create user webapp encrypted password '' in role app;

-- grant privileges to dba role
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to dba;

------------------------
-- RESTORE 
------------------------
psql -U postgres -d uat -h localhost -W -p 5432 < uat.sql
```

But when I logged in as user `dev1` for example, I can't do anything:

```
select * from guru_basket_security;
```

Listing access for this table:

```
    \z    
                                                              Access privileges
     Schema |                         Name                         |   Type   |     Access privileges     | Column privileges | Policies 
    --------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------
     public | guru_basket_security                                 | table    |                           |                   | 
     public | identifier                                           | table    | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres |                   |
```

I got these errors:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation guru_basket_security
ERROR:  permission denied for relation identifier
```

Answer (score 5):

The concept of groups & users has largely been done away with in PostgreSQL, with the terms USER and GROUP may be interchangeably used with ROLE. [See documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html).

Suffice to say that what you want to do is create your "group" role first like this:

```
CREATE ROLE devs NOLOGIN;
```

Then grant all desired permissions to devs. Now create the users with `IN ROLE devs` clause like this:

```
CREATE ROLE jsmith LOGIN INHERIT IN ROLE devs ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '...' ...;
CREATE ROLE sjones LOGIN INHERIT IN ROLE devs ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '...' ...;
...
```

This will allow "real" users to login & inherit all the same permissions but no one can explicitly become devs (or the "group" role).

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I tried your suggestion but I can't do any operation on my database now. Maybe we're missing something about the privileges ?

Comment: In your updated statements you only have one `GRANT` statement--and that's for the  `dba` role. You didn't (at least show the) grant any permissions for the  `dba` role.

Comment: Okay, I will try to give the same privileges to the `dev` as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I manage to solve my problem:

```
------------------------
-- INITIAL SETUP
------------------------

-- create uat database
create database uat;

-- dba role
create role dba with superuser createdb createrole nologin replication bypassrls;

-- dev role
create role dev with nosuperuser nocreatedb nocreaterole nologin noreplication nobypassrls;

-- app role
create role app with nosuperuser nocreatedb nocreaterole nologin noreplication nobypassrls;

-- alter postgres password
alter role postgres encrypted password '';

-- create users
create user dev1 login inherit encrypted password '' in role dev;
create user dev2 login inherit encrypted password '' in role dev;
create user dev3 login inherit encrypted password '' in role dev;

create user dba login inherit encrypted password '' in role dba;

create user app1 encrypted password '' in role app;

grant usage on schema public to dba;
grant usage on schema public to dev;
grant usage on schema public to app;

alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to dba;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to dev;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to app;

alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to dba;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to dev;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to app;

revoke connect on database uat from public;

grant connect on database uat to dba;
grant connect on database uat to dev;
grant connect on database uat to app;

------------------------
-- RESTORE 
------------------------

psql -U postgres -d uat -h localhost -W -p 5432 < uat.clean.sql 

------------------------
-- REVOKE AND GRANT
------------------------
psql -U postgres -d uat -h localhost -W -p 5432

-- connect into uat
\c uat

grant usage on schema public to dba; 
grant select on all tables in schema public to dba; 
grant select on all sequences in schema public to dba;

grant usage on schema public to dev; 
grant select on all tables in schema public to dev; 
grant select on all sequences in schema public to dev;

grant usage on schema public to app; 
grant select on all tables in schema public to app; 
grant select on all sequences in schema public to app;  

-- grant privileges
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to dba;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to dev;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to app;
```